# Italicized or emphasized text is not displaying

Tags: italic, emphasis

There's an infinite loop with the Captcha under Chrome, so once again I have to use this avatar.

I have two issues with my document and would appreciate assistance. For some reason italics or emphasized text are not appearing.

The syntax I originally used was

```
\begin{textit}
Some text.
\end{textit}
```

But only the initial "S" was italicized. So I tried changing to:

```
\begin{emph}
Some text.
\end{emph}
```

but got the same result.

MWE follows.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{italic}`. Use `\textit{}` or `\itshape`.

Comment: Why `\begin{emph}`? Just type `\emph{words words}`.

Comment: Sorry, I did originally use \begin{textit} some text \end{textit}. There were compile errors. I thought that maybe as this is compiled under pdflatex there might be a font issue.

Comment: The reason for \begin{emph}...\end{emph} is a coding best practice designed to avoid unclosed arguments. Since I don't know where the problem is, I don't know if this is an issue or not.

Answer (score 3):

`\begin{textit}Some text\end{textit}` is wrong; there is the *command* `\textit` that takes as argument the text you want to typeset in italics.

What happens is essentially equivalent to doing

```
\begingroup\textit Some text\relax\endgroup
```

and `\textit` considers only `S` as its argument: when there are no braces, a macro with argument takes for it the first token only.

If you want to define an environment for typesetting some text in italics, do

```
\newenvironment{italics}
  {\itshape\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{italics}
  {\itshape\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{italics}
then some text in italics
\end{italics}
and then text in Roman type.

Some text before \textit{then some text in italics}
and then text in Roman type.

\end{document}
```

I'd advise you to use the second form.

[image]

If you want to have the environment equivalent to `\emph`, it should be

```
\newenvironment{emphasis}
  {\em\ignorespaces}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Of course the environment's name is up to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the sentences you want emphasized with `\emph{...}`. Concerning the `enumerate` environments, add `\itshape`.

So in summary, do like this:

```
\emph{The provisions of this Law are valid for:}

\begin{enumerate*}\itshape
\item [1.] ...
\item [2.] ...
\item [3.] ... 
\end{enumerate*}
```

[image]